# Access function pointer defined in a structure?

Tags: c, structure, function-pointers

Write a program to access the function "foo" using the structure structure2.

```
typedef struct
{
   int *a;
   char (*fptr)(char*);
}structure1;

typedef struct
{
   int x;
   structure1 *ptr;
}structure2;

char foo(char * c)
{
---
---
---
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
structure2 *s2 = (structure2*)malloc(sizeof(structure2));
s2->ptr = (structure1*)malloc(sizeof(structure1));
s2->ptr->fptr = foo;
char x = 'a';
s2->ptr->fptr(&x);
```

Answer (score 0):

- Create an object of type `structure2`
- Assign to it the address of an object of type `structure1` (this can be done in quite a few ways)
- Assign `foo` to the above allocated `structure1` object's `fptr` member
- Call `foo` using:

  ```
  structure2 s2;
  // allocate 
  char c = 42;
  s2.ptr->fptr(&c);  // if this
  ```

Example:

```
typedef struct
{
   int *a;
   char (*fptr)(char*);
}structure1;

typedef struct
{
   int x;
   structure1 *ptr;
}structure2;

char foo(char * c)
{
return 'c';
}

int main()
{
 structure1 s1;
 structure2 s2;
 s1.fptr = foo;
 s2.ptr = &s1; 
 char c = 'c';
 printf("%c\n", s2.ptr->fptr(&c));
return 0;
}
```